# highlight XML tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have textarea which can contain XML tags and I would like to have something like button which will toggle on/off highlightion of XML tags...

Is there any function that could take care of this problem, or do I need to implement my own one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you have to do by yourself, using a regexp for instance.

Comment: use ajax and rejex in javascript to find xml tags and display the code (currently in textarea) below it (with XML text highlighted) ie the same way you highlight, bold ,add code while asking a question on stack overflow and you get a visual of how it will look when submitted.